# Casting function pointers with arguments of different pointer types

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int i;
} A;

void f(A* a) {
    printf("%d\n", a->i);
}

int main() {
    void (*pf)(void*) = (void(*)(void*))&f;
    A a;
    pf(&a); // 1
    ((void(*)(A*))pf)(&a); // 2
}
```

A function pointer `void(*)(A*)` is cast to a function pointer `void(*)(void*)`. Then it is called with an argument of type `A*`.

Is it guaranteed to work correctly when used directly (1)? Or it is needed to cast it back like (2)?

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all. The casts between pointer to functions with different signatures are allowed by [C11 standard, 6.3.2.3p8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8)

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

### Method 1

> `pf(&a);` // 1

No. This is undefined behavior and it is not guaranteed to work. From [C11 standard, 6.3.2.3p8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8):

> ... If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

### Method 2

> `((void(*)(A*))pf)(&a);` // 2

It is fine and defined. because the function with signature `void(A*)` is called via a pointer to `void(A*)`.

### EDIT

The compatibility of function types is defined in [6.7.6.3p15](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15):

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify **compatible return types**. Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; **corresponding parameters shall have compatible types**. ...

The functions `void(void*)` and `void(A*)` are not compatible because types `void*` and `A*` are not compatible.